# Accessing JSON Object with a datetype like key

Tags: json, node.js

Please Help me. I have JSON data like this :

[image]

The JSON was generated by nodeJS client.query multiple statement and the result stored in `rows_final`

I try to access the key, for example 2012-01-01 so I write my code like this :

```
JSON.stringify(rows_final[3][0].2012-01-01)
```

The result is error like this :

[image]

But if I try to access the other key, for example the **nip** key, there is no problem

How to access that key in a proper way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2012-01-01 is an invalid name for a javascript variable. Trying access it like so:

```
JSON.stringify(rows_final[3][0]['2012-01-01'])
```

Here is a simpler example:

```
var s = '{"x":1,"2012-01-01":2}';
var o = JSON.parse(s);
console.log(o.x);
console.log(o['2012-01-01']);
```

Output:

```
1
2
```